# How do I replace a string that starts with "[id", has an unknown middle part and ends in "]"?

Tags: php, regex, string, replace

I would like to replace strings that starts with "[id", has a middle part unknown and ends in "]" in a $text. I know how to replace strings that starts with "[id" and ends with "]" but I can't figure out how to include the unknown middle body part as a rule of replace.

Any ideas how to replace like this ?

Thanks.

Comment: I suggest you use Regular Expressions. Use this site to help you form your search pattern: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: What if 'middle part unknown' contains a ']' character?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following will remove all occurences of `[id`*something*`]`. *something* will match all characters except for `]`.

```
$newText = preg_replace('#\[id[^\]]+\]#', '', $subject);
```

If you know that *something* is always a digit, you could use something like this:

```
$newText = preg_replace('#\[id\d+\]#', '', $subject);
```

For more information about regular expressions, see this website: http://www.regular-expressions.info/.

Answer (score 4):

The string replace functions can only work on specific strings. If you have a *pattern* you want to match, you should use [`preg_replace`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php), which replaces based on regular expressions:

```
$text = preg_replace('/\[id[^\]]*\]/', $replacement, $text)
// $replacement is whatever string you want to replace with
```

`/\[id[^\]]*\]/` is a [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) (aka *regex*). The slashes on each end are [delimiters](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) which PHP requires to delineate a regex. The rest of the pattern can be described as follows:

```
\[     # match a literal [ character
id     # match the string "id"
[^     # open a negated character class
  \]   # match anything other than literal ] character (since it's in a negated class)
]*     # close the class, repeat it zero or more times
\]     # match a literal ]
```

Concepts:

- [Character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) - a character class is a way of describing that a character can be one of a series of possibilities. Character classes start with a `[` and end with a `]`. For example, `[abc]` matches `a` *or* `b` *or* `c`. Character classes can be *negated* if the first character within a class is `^`: `[^abc]` matches any character that *isn't* `a` *or* `b` *or* `c`. In our pattern, `[^\]]` matches any character that isn't `]`. Note that the `]` within the class has to be *escaped* because `]` generally means the end of the class but we want to specify a literal `]` character.
- [Repetition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) using `*` - Parts of patterns can be repeated (which allows for a pattern to specify that something can appear multiple times). There are three repetition operators: `?` specifies that something may appear zero or one times (ie. it makes part of your pattern [optional](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html)); `*` specifies that something may appear zero or more times (ie. it can be optional, but it could also any number of times); `+` specifies something that must appear at least once.
  In our case; `[^\]]*` specifies that a character that is not `]` can be matched zero or more times - this will match an empty string, or will match `abcdefg`, as the negated character class matches 7 times (as each character is not `]`).
  Note that by default, regexes are [*greedy*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#greedy), which means that they will match as much of the string as possible; for this reason `[^\]]*` when matched against `abcdefg` will match the entire string, as that is the largest match it can make (even though smaller substrings match the pattern).
- Everything else in this pattern matches literally. As we saw above, `[` and `]` need to be escaped to match the literal characters - because they have meaning within a regex (ie. to define a character class) - but `id` matches an `i` followed immediately by a `d`.

When you put that all together, you end up with a pattern that matches a opening bracket, followed by the letters `id`, followed by zero or more characters and then a closing bracket.

Note if you wanted to make this pattern case-insensitive, you could add an `i` after the final slash: `/\[id[^\]]*\]/i`. `/i` is a [modifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) which makes the entire pattern case insensitive (so it'd match `[ID=...]` as well).

I recommend reading through the [tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) on regular-expressions.info if you are not familiar with regexes, as it will give you a very good understanding of what they do and how to compose them.

Answer (score 2):

using `preg_replace()`:

```
<?php

    $text = "[hi=hello] [id=hellomynameisjoe] [hello=hi]";
    $new = preg_replace('@\[id[^\]]+\]@', '[replaced!]', $text);
    echo $new;
?>
```

Comment: Note that lazy patterns are less efficient as they cause a lot of backtracking. See http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/greedy-lazy-performance

Comment: I wonder why I'm so used to that. Thanks for the info, editing my code.